# swapping <div>?

Tags: jquery-ui

div #1first.

addquestion button

```
    <div id="id-2" class name="data"><div>div #2</div><span>second.</span></div>
```

addquestion button

```
    <div id="id-3" class name="data"><div>div #3</div><span>third.</span></div>
```

addquestion button

```
    <div id="id-4" class name="data"><div>div #4</div><span>last.</span></div>
```

addquestion button

```
</body>
```

i want to swap the id-3 with the next div that is id-4. i know only the id-3

Comment: If you know only the third `div`, how can you swap it with an unknown fourth `div`? I don't understand this question at all.

Comment: i mean to say tht i want to swap with the next <div> with same class name . in my case if its id-3 i want to replace it with id-4. Is tht clear @Blender. thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('div').click(function()
{
  $(this).html($(this).next('.data').html());
});
```

I'm not sure if `next()` cycles to the beginning, but it's worth a try.